# Why I can't use the get() method in tkinter (python) with a grid() arrangement?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, input, methods

I want to read out an input from an input field in a GUI. My Problem is that my Code don't work if I use the grid() method for the order. If I use the pack() method it works...
What I have to do, that the get() method also works in combination with the grid() method?

e.g. for work with pack()

```
from tkinter import *  

def function1():
    ci = e1.get()
    print(c1)

window = Tk()

e1 = Entry(window)
b1 = Button(text="Ok", command=read_input_field)

e1.pack()
b1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

e.g. for doesn't work with grid()

```
from tkinter import *  

def function1():
    ci = e1.get()
    print(c1)

window = Tk()

e1 = Entry(window).grid(row=1, column=2)
b1 = Button(text="Ok", command=read_input_field).grid(row=1, column=2) 

window.mainloop()
```

I hope you can help me.

A warm thank you in advance

tron

Answer (score 0):

The PROBLEM is that the `.grid` method returns nothing, so `b1` has the wrong value.  You need to do that as two separate lines:

```
b1 = Button(text="Ok", command=read_input_field)
b1.grid(row=1, column=2)
```

tkinter was designed more than a generation ago.  It is not object-oriented in any way.